# Pulling all images from WordPress wp-uploads folder in template page using php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, upload

I have created a static website page http://tattscan.com/css-only-page-2/ with a image gallery.  I have also changed the WP default gallery styling to match the static gallery.  Now I would like to change my static picture gallery dynamic by pulling all images loaded in WordPress wp-upload folder to populate this gallery.  Is there some simple php code to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're hosting that page inside WordPress, so while you've access-to/loaded WP environment, you can fetch all media uploads and loop through it. Code from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/get-all-images-in-media-gallery) answer,

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}
```

Remember to tweak the code to your needs.

Edit 1: To display all the images

Replace the following code

```
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}
```

with

```
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
    echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID ) . '"/>';
}
```

Comment: I input the code, but it didn't return anything.  Do I need to link database, db user and password before code?  Coding not returning anything at the moment http://tattscan.com/all-media-dynamic/ .  Thanks a bunch, very new to this!

Comment: This code itself won't print anything. Right after the code above, put this `print_r( $images );` and then check the output. *As I mentioned above, tweak the code to your needs.

Comment: ok, I threw print_r( $images ); in there after code and it jacked the whole page up.  So I'm a bit lost...http://tattscan.com/all-media-dynamic/

Comment: These are all images in your WP Media. You can loop through it and use it to your own benefit.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get the code to show each image instead of the text, can you give me an example of loop for this?

Comment: Junaid, thanks for your help.  This worked for me, many thanks!